# ExtensionForceInstallList Chrome Browsers Not Auto-Updating

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In our product we force install the Chrome extension we ship via Policy setting ExtensionForceInstallList. The setting is in the proper format and initially installs our Chrome extension from the Google web store just fine.

The problem is when I publish a newer version those same clients do not pull down the new version unless our tester goes to the Manage Extensions page and clicks Update.

These were on clients that brought up the Chrome browser today (a Tuesday) on a Chrome extension that was formally "published" on the previous Friday.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: No errors seen @jess. It was more of a question do I require more registry settings other than Policies / ExtensionForeInstallList.